# SonarQube 6.2 upgrade to 6.4 Missing projects and users

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

On Debian Jessie I had an installed version of SonarQube 6.2 using Postgresql (latest on Jessie )
Java 8 installed
I went through the upgrade process (to v. 6.4)[Here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading)

When it came back online all the projects were missing.  I can get to them by manually typing in the URL to the project like:

`https://[address of server]/dashboard?id=[Name of Project]`

Also the in the user admin section (Administration>Security>Users) I see no users.
However if I go to groups (Administration>Security>Groups) my sonar user group says it has users.  In my case its 14 - but I cannot see any of them.
Can anyone help bring this stuff back? I did do a DB back-up before the upgrade - so I can always go back, but I would like to not have to do that.

Comment: Projects are "missing" from where?

Comment: Everywhere from the gui's perspective that I found except where I noted in the manual url entry. I guess the page that you could consider most noteworthy is the the "Projects" page/tab even after hitting "All"

Comment: Can you log in as an admin and double-check project permissions to make sure that 'Browse' is granted to the users/groups you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newly upgraded Sonar not showing projects or users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408205/newly-upgraded-sonar-not-showing-projects-or-users)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44409958/2662707), this seems to be a bad ElasticSearch index. Stop your server. Delete *$SONARQUBE_HOME/data* and restart.

Comment: SonarQube went into maintenance  mode upon start-up and it took like 60-75 seconds and then came out of it and everything looks fantastic - back to normal.  Thank you