# Newly upgraded Sonar not showing projects or users

Tags: sonarqube

Hi the problem i am having is after upgrading from 5.1.2 -> 5.6 -> 6.4. I believe i followed the upgrade path as documented. 
The system worked fine on 5.1.2 & 5.6 but now on 6.4 the initial projects page that loads first thing is empty. It reads "Once you analyze some projects, they will show up here." Does this mean i need to analyse new projects? It does not pull the old analysis from the previous versions?

If i go into administration -> projects -> management i see all the projects in there.

Also if i go into administration -> security -> users all i see in the admin user. (i am not logged in as admin i am logged in as tbusby)
If i go to administration -> security -> groups i see groups and all the members e.g. sonar-users - 23users.

We use Crowd as our user repository and it seems to be authenticating fine just not displaying the users.

Just wondering if this behaviour is expected with the new UI and i am just reading things wrong or there is an actual issue.

Kind Regards
Tom Busby

Comment: just in case, drop the elastic search working dir ( /data/es ) then restart

Comment: Thanks Bernard this worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube 6.2 upgrade to 6.4 Missing projects and users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398240/sonarqube-6-2-upgrade-to-6-4-missing-projects-and-users)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I upgraded from 6.3.1 to 6.4 and are using Azure AD to authenticate. I saw the exact same behavior as Tom Busby. After deleting everything below /data/es as Bernard Dubreuil suggested it is working as expected again!